# Сортировка с параметром

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица:

- id|name |cost|count
- 1 |prod1|100 |100
- 2 |prod2|50  |30
- 3 |prod3|10  |0
- 4 |prod4|60  |0

Нужно получить:

- id|name |cost|count
- 2 |prod2|50  |30
- 1 |prod1|100 |100
- 3 |prod3|10  |0
- 4 |prod4|60  |0

т.е. отсортировать по цене, но прим этом те у которых count = 0, выводить последними

Comment: `ORDER BY count != 0 , count`

Comment: @Akina, Видимо, подразумевалось ORDER BY count = 0, cost ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
select * 
from tab
order by case when count=0 then power(10,10) else cost end;
```

[Тест на SQLFiddle ...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dd25e/3)

Comment: а чем плох вариант `ORDER BY count = 0 ASC, cost ASC` ?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский, всем хорош, только его уже предложили а комментах. ;-)